# how to update mpicc?

Tags: c++11, gcc, mpi

I run a mpicc with  -std=c++11 and meet an error, the message is :
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

I search it and find that it's because the gcc version is too old. I download gcc 5.1 tgz then make and install, and replace old gcc with new gcc , by add the direction to path , and I use gcc --version /g++ --version , I find the version is new now.

But when I use mpicc --versioin, I find it's still old version, so I still cannot compile my file. I try to make mpich and install it again, but there is nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in this way:
firstly, use "mpicc -compile_info" to get what mpicc call
in my system, it calls c++ ...
then, use "which c++" to find the path and use the new g++ to update it

Comment: I guess, you realise `-compile_info` is an option specific to certain MPI implementation and without mentioning which one it is, your question and the answer are of little help to other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenMPI, you can set `OMPI_CC` and `OMPI_CXX` to provide the C or C++ compiler, respectively.

I.e.

```
export OMPI_CXX=$(which g++)
```